# Passing session info from python to flex

Tags: python, django, apache-flex, pyamf

I have a simple site made with python (django).  User registers, inputs some basic info and it stores it to mysql.  User then is able to log in with his username/password which he created...

Now i want to add a flex application which will run once the user is logged in, but i dont want the user to have to log in twice (once into django, once into flex app). For the sake of learning i just want the flex app to also load some information from the mysql database, like the users firstname or something.

So my question is how would i go about passing session information into the flex app? Any info or guidance, or opinion would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If your Python/DJango app uses cookies for tracking sessions; then you just have to make sure that your SWF is served off the same domain that the Python app is served from.

The Flash Player will pass the appropriate cookies to the remote server whenever it makes a call to that server.  As long as your "Flash Call" exists in the same Application space on the server, it should have access to the same session variables available on the server.

If you want to validate the user has logged in before loading the SWF; just make a remote call from the SWF to the server side to validate that the session exists, and the user is appropriately logged in.  Don't activate any of the controls in the app until you get confirmation from the server that the user is allowed to use the app.